# Como duplicar Objetos em Javascript

Tags: javascript, objetos

Um dos recursos mais requisitados frequentemente por novos desenvolvedores JavaScript é como duplicar um objeto. Parece como se devesse existir um método nativo `copy()`, certo? Acontece que é um pouco mais complicado que isso, porque não é totalmente claro, por padrão, **qual deveria ser o algoritmo para a duplicação?**

Comment: Que tipo de objeto? Ele pode ser representado num JSON?

Comment: Sim pode ser representado num JSON.

Comment: Não chega `const copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));`?

Comment: Atenção que nem sempre um objeto será JSON-safe. **_JSON-safe_ que pode ser serializado para uma string JSON e depois re-transformada em um objeto com a mesma estrutura e valores**

Comment: Se tiver funções associadas de facto elas perdem-se nesse exemplo com `JSON.parse` e `JSON.stringify`, mas isso foi algo que você não clarificou na pergunta. Independentemente disso a pergunta marcada como duplicada tem respostas mesmo para esse caso.

Comment: Sergio e Isac Obrigado pelo feedback. De facto a outra pergunta já tem respostas que estava a procura.